# Как сделать, что бы видео с vimeo проигрывались один за другим без перерыва?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать, что бы видео с vimeo проигрывались один за другим без остановки?

Answer (score 1):

потенциальный ответ на ваш вапрос    [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032873/getting-video-source-continuously-one-after-another-in-one-video-tag-using-javas)

сдесь есть пример http://jsfiddle.net/m78zz/

```
---
```

Answer (score 0):

//videos -  массив с плейлистом

```
  player.on('ended', function() {
      console.log('ended the video!');
      var i = (videos.indexOf(id)+1)%videos.length;
      id = videos[i];
      player.loadVideo(videos[i]).then(function(){
        player.play().then(function() {
            // the video was played
        }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log(error.name);
        });   
      });
      var vf = videos_full[i];
      $('#the_name').text(vf.name);
      document.title = vf.name;
      $('#the_desc').text(vf.desc);
      history.pushState(null, null, vf.url);
  });
```